# ldd -r -v How do I add version symbol to file?

Tags: linux, gcc, binutils

```
Version information:
./VideoEncoderFilter.so:
    libgcc_s.so.1 (GCC_3.0) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
    libva.so.1 (VA_API_0.34.0) => not found
    libdl.so.2 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
    libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4.20) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
    libstdc++.so.6 (CXXABI_1.3.8) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
    libstdc++.so.6 (CXXABI_1.3.9) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
    libstdc++.so.6 (CXXABI_1.3) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
    libstdc++.so.6 (GLIBCXX_3.4.15) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
```

I am curious how this version symbol `VA_API_0.34.0` added to `VideoEncoderFilter.so`.

If I have a foo.c and I want to create a version symbol `FOO_API_0.34.0`, what do I do?

```
gcc -c -fPIC foo.c -o foo.o
gcc foo.o -shared -o libfoo.so
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU ld supports [version scripts](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/VERSION.html). If you want to add the version `FOO_API_0.34.0` to the symbol `foo`, you can do it like this:

```
$ cat libfoo.versions
FOO_API_0.34.0 {
  global: foo;
};
$ gcc -c -fPIC foo.c -o foo.o
$ gcc foo.o -shared -o libfoo.so -Wl,--version-script=libfoo.versions
```

You can verify that the symbol is there using `readelf`:

```
$ readelf --dyn-syms -W libfoo.so

Symbol table '.dynsym' contains 7 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
     1: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
     2: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __gmon_start__
     3: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
     4: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.2.5 (3)
     5: 0000000000000000     0 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT  ABS FOO_API_0.34.0
     6: 00000000000010f5    11 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 foo@@FOO_API_0.34.0
```

Comment: so the linker will automatically refuse to link libfoo.so other than FOO_API_0.34.0?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Would you please rephrase?

Comment: Sorry, my bad English.  For example, I compile main.c with libfoo.so(FOO_API_0.34.0) to "a.out", and then I replace the libfoo.so(FOO_API_0.34.0) with libfoo.so(FOO_API_0.35.0). The program "a.out" now can not be run, right?
Suppose libfoo.so(FOO_API_0.35.0) is exact the same with the older one except libfoo.versions.

Comment: So basically, "-Wl,--version-script=libfoo.versions" just add a symbol to libfoo.so. And the executable file must to find all the symbol exist. Using this technique can archive avoiding user misuse the unsupported dynamic library. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's basically correct. You can export several versions for the same symbol from the shared library, for example using the GCC function attribute `symver` (available in GCC 10 or later).